# For what values of a and b are the vectors linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Find all values of a and b for which the vectors $f=-x^2-2x+5$, $g=ax+3$, and $h=x+b$ in $C^∞(R)$ are linearly independent

To solve this, from the equations I got the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
-2 & a & 1 \\
5 & 3 & b \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and then I found the determinant of the matrix and got $ a\cdot b-3=0 $ which would be $ a=3/b $ but since there is more variables than equations wouldn't it be inconsistent?

Comment: What is the meaning of $\det(A)$ in term of linearly independence?

Comment: Try to follow the given hint and formulate an answer here, we'll take  a look to it.

Comment: I edited my post to the information. I already knew that but because I got a=3/b I thought I was doing something wrong so I am still stuck

Comment: Your derivation is ok. The condition for linear independence is exactly what you have found out, that is: $a\cdot b-3 \neq 0$. Then, for example, if we take $a=3$ and $b = 1$, what can we conclude?

Comment: that it's not linearly independent if a=3 and b=1

Comment: Exactly you get the idea now! For each pair $(a,b)$ such that $ab-3=0$ we have linear dependence. Can you visualize that condition?

Comment: Take a look here http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+a*b%3D3

Comment: We don't have a single solution but infinitely many solutions for the pairs $(a,b)$ which leads to linear dependence.

Comment: would it be infinitely many solutions? because it would be all solutions for a*b=3

Comment: Yes exactly! $a\cdot b = 3 \implies$ linear dependence $a\cdot b \neq 3 \implies$ linear independence.